# Unity Android build failure: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: android, windows, unity-game-engine, build-error

Building a Unity project for Android failures at last steps, here what I get in the console:

`Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.4f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe
...
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.`

How to understand what is going wrong and fix it?

**Full error text:**

```
Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.4f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="D:\Projects\Unity3d\MyGame\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="D:\Projects\Unity3d\MyGame\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.4f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.4f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.4f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK" --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.4f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe" --directory=D:/Projects/Unity3d/MyGame/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed --generatedcppdir=D:/Projects/Unity3d/MyGame/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput 


stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: D:\Projects\Unity3d\MyGame\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a
    Cache directory: D:\Projects\Unity3d\MyGame\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.RunWithResult[D,T](D[] data, Func`2 action)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o) (Inner Exception #1) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o) (Inner Exception #2) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o) (Inner Exception #3) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o) (Inner Exception #4) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o) (Inner Exception #5) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o) (Inner Exception #6) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o) (Inner Exception #7) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(Object o)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.RunWithResult[D,T](D[] data, Func`2 action)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:126)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:71)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:503)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(String, String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:484)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:334)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:63)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: What is your NDK version?

Comment: `Pkg.Revision = 16.1.4479499` from the `source.properties` file. Everything's been installed via Unity Hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried installing/reinstalling all kind of android tools, Unity editor, Visual Studio (yet I didn't try reinstalling Windows :). Finally, trying to solve another problem I tried to change `Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings -> Configuration -> Scripting Backed`, it changed it from `IL2CCP` to `Mono` and it cured my building errors (and building process got faster).

I still don't know why I'm the only one from the project team who has to deal with this issue when `IL2CCP` is selected, but at least now I can debug the project.

If you are interested in what is the difference between and here are [good answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140493/difference-between-unity-scripting-backend-il2cpp-and-mono2x) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in unity ndk itself is buggy, you need to install a stable version from google android developer page: [Android NDK, Revision 16b (December 2017)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html#ndk-16b-downloads).

Comment: I downloaded and unpacked it in a folder. Then in *Unity -> Preferences -> External tools* turned off the *"Android NDK Installed with my Unity"* checkbox and selected the path to the downloaded folder. It didn't help, the error message is still the same.

Comment: @Sergey, then this is a bug in unity itself, try upgrading to the latest stable version.

Comment: Several people are working on the project but I'm the only one experiencing this problem. They won't agree to change the version.

Comment: @Sergey did you try to compile an unity default empty project?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem in a slightly different way. Thanks for your help a lot!